# why jquery hide the arrow insted of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the problem in this code:

```
<style type="text/css">

    #container{
        width: 266px ;
        height:128px ;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".left-arrow").click(function(){
            $(".large-photo").fadeOut(1000);

        });
    });


</script> 

<div id="container">
<div class="large-photo">
         <img src="images/1395924816_personal-information.png">
         <img src="images/1395938204_lock.png">
     </div>
     <div class="small-photo">
         <img src="images/1395939936_application-pgp-signature.png" >
         <img src="images/1396010974_button-cross_basic_red.png" >
     </div>

    </div>
     <div class="arrow">
          <a href="#" onclick="remove();" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a> 
          <a href="#" id="right-arrow">-></a> 
      </div>
```

the problem with this is that when i click `left-arrow` it dosen't hide `large-image` instead it hide itself i.e jquery instead of hiding `large-image` hides `left arrow`. please help me in this...

and yes here is a fiddle of my code =====> [`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/sUb4A/)

thanks

but you all are writing to remove `onclick="remove();"`... why?

Comment: `onclick="remove();"` can be removed

Comment: Perhaps because of the remove() in the "onclick" handler of #left-arrow?

Comment: @anni - What you want to achieve with `onclick="remove();"` ?

Comment: well earlier i was trying to do this with javascript but then i stated doing this tsk using jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `left-arrow` is an `ID` You should use `#` as an ID selector instead of `.` which is class selector:

```
$("#left-arrow").click(function(){
```

instead of

```
$(".left-arrow").click(function(){
```

and second remove `onclick()` from this markup

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove();" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a> <!-- Remove onclick() -->
```

---

```
<a href="#" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sUb4A/11/)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#left-arrow").click(function(){
        $(".large-photo").fadeOut(1000);
   });
});
```

and whatever you write in "onclick=remove();", in

```
<a href="#" onclick="remove();" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a>
```

it also effect in code remove it also or check for that code, or try

```
<a href="#" id="left-arrow">&lt;-</a>
```

it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign as id `#` like this:

`#left-arrow`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#left-arrow").click(function(){
            $(".large-photo").fadeOut(1000);

        });
    });
```

and remove `onclick="remove();"`

Answer (score 1):

because you have `onclick="remove();"` on the arrow

that removes it :)

and you have a typo with id (#) and class (.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to handle click of `.left-arrow` which is a `class`. But you defined arrows in your code as `id`. so this is the new version:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUb4A/12/

Answer (score 1):

First,
its `$("#left-arrow").click(function(){});` left-arrow is an ID not a CLASS.

and next,

remove the `onclick="remove();`

Check this **[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/3ARLV/)**

Answer (score 0):

you are looking at sympthomes that your click event is calling your jQuery code.

First, there is no reference between `<a id="left-arrow">` and `$(".left-arrow")`. Please change to `#` at your selector (as all others said before). Second, you define a inline click handler `<a onclick="remove()"`. If you click this link JS removes your node from DOM. There is no *reference error* because `remove()` is defined as function with some [native code].

You can proof my explanation via deleting your jQuery code and click at `<a id="left-arrow" onclick=" console.log(typeof remove, remove); remove();'">`.

I create a small [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld9bj/) for you. Feel free to ask questions to my code.